# Problema com persistencia com spring

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, spring-boot, persistência

O erro:
**java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not an entity: class br.com.api.entities.Characters**

Minha Class

```
package br.com.api.entities;

import java.time.LocalDateTime;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class Characters {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;
private String name;
private String description;
private LocalDateTime modified;
private String resourceURI;

public Characters() {

}

// Getters and Setters
```

A grande incógnita aqui é que quando eu pego o **Metamodel**
para verificar se minha entidade lá esta, ela realmente aparece *Characters*.

```
public static void getAnnotatedClasses() {
    EntityManager em = null;
    try {
        em = sessionFactory.createEntityManager();
        em.getMetamodel().getEntities().forEach(System.out::println); // Characters 
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (em != null) {
            em.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Meu Controller

```
package br.com.api.controls;

import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import br.com.api.entities.Characters;
import br.com.hcf.HCFConnection;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("api/v1/public")
public class CharacterControl {

    @GetMapping("/characters")
    public ResponseEntity<Object> getAll() {
        try {
            return ResponseEntity.ok(new HCFConnection<>(Characters.class).all());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND).body("Characters not found");
        }
    }

}
```

StackTrace

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v2.4.4)

2021-04-14 19:49:08.650  INFO 1300 --- [  restartedMain] br.com.api.ApiApplication                : Starting ApiApplication using Java 15.0.2 on DESKTOP-TEEJGQ6 with PID 1300 (C:\Users\karpi\Desktop\api-hcf\target\classes started by karpi in C:\Users\karpi\Desktop\api-hcf)
2021-04-14 19:49:08.656  INFO 1300 --- [  restartedMain] br.com.api.ApiApplication                : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2021-04-14 19:49:08.802  INFO 1300 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : Devtools property defaults active! Set 'spring.devtools.add-properties' to 'false' to disable
2021-04-14 19:49:08.803  INFO 1300 --- [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : For additional web related logging consider setting the 'logging.level.web' property to 'DEBUG'
2021-04-14 19:49:10.889  INFO 1300 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2021-04-14 19:49:10.912  INFO 1300 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2021-04-14 19:49:10.913  INFO 1300 --- [  restartedMain] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.44]
2021-04-14 19:49:11.104  INFO 1300 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2021-04-14 19:49:11.105  INFO 1300 --- [  restartedMain] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 2300 ms
2021-04-14 19:49:11.521  INFO 1300 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2021-04-14 19:49:11.958  INFO 1300 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.a.OptionalLiveReloadServer       : LiveReload server is running on port 35729
2021-04-14 19:49:12.062  INFO 1300 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2021-04-14 19:49:12.081  INFO 1300 --- [  restartedMain] br.com.api.ApiApplication                : Started ApiApplication in 4.132 seconds (JVM running for 5.101)
2021-04-14 19:49:18.535  INFO 1300 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2021-04-14 19:49:18.535  INFO 1300 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2021-04-14 19:49:18.536  INFO 1300 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 1 ms
2021-04-14 19:49:18.700  INFO 1300 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.4.29.Final
2021-04-14 19:49:18.705  INFO 1300 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000205: Loaded properties from resource hibernate.properties: {hibernate.format_sql=false, hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=update, hibernate.c3p0.max_size=10, hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect, hibernate.c3p0.min_size=5, hibernate.connection.username=root, hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans=true, hibernate.connection.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/springboot?useTimezone=true&serverTimezone=America/Sao_Paulo, hibernate.show_sql=false, hibernate.connection.driver_class=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver, hibernate.c3p0.max_statements=30, hibernate.connection.password=****, hibernate.c3p0.timeout=3000, hibernate.bytecode.use_reflection_optimizer=false}
2021-04-14 19:49:23.659  INFO 1300 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.2.Final}
2021-04-14 19:49:23.812  WARN 1300 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.e.j.c.i.ConnectionProviderInitiator  : HHH000022: c3p0 properties were encountered, but the c3p0 provider class was not found on the classpath; these properties are going to be ignored.
2021-04-14 19:49:23.815  WARN 1300 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] org.hibernate.orm.connections.pooling    : HHH10001002: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
2021-04-14 19:49:23.825  INFO 1300 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] org.hibernate.orm.connections.pooling    : HHH10001005: using driver [com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver] at URL [jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/springboot?useTimezone=true&serverTimezone=America/Sao_Paulo]
2021-04-14 19:49:23.826  INFO 1300 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] org.hibernate.orm.connections.pooling    : HHH10001001: Connection properties: {password=****, user=root}
2021-04-14 19:49:23.827  INFO 1300 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] org.hibernate.orm.connections.pooling    : HHH10001003: Autocommit mode: false
2021-04-14 19:49:23.833  INFO 1300 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] .c.i.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl : HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 20 (min=1)
2021-04-14 19:49:24.398  INFO 1300 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
2021-04-14 19:49:25.263  INFO 1300 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] org.hibernate.orm.connections.access     : HHH10001501: Connection obtained from JdbcConnectionAccess [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess@3818bf61] for (non-JTA) DDL execution was not in auto-commit mode; the Connection 'local transaction' will be committed and the Connection will be set into auto-commit mode.
2021-04-14 19:49:25.310  INFO 1300 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not an entity: class br.com.api.entities.Characters
    at org.hibernate.metamodel.internal.MetamodelImpl.entity(MetamodelImpl.java:566)
    at org.hibernate.query.criteria.internal.QueryStructure.from(QueryStructure.java:127)
    at org.hibernate.query.criteria.internal.CriteriaQueryImpl.from(CriteriaQueryImpl.java:158)
    at br.com.hcf.HCFConnection.all(HCFConnection.java:139)
    at br.com.api.controls.CharacterControl.getAll(CharacterControl.java:19)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:197)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:141)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:106)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:894)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1060)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:962)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:626)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:143)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:374)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:893)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1707)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
```

Descobri que em main funciona 100%, o problema e com o spring mesmo.

```
19:26:33.039 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.loader.plan.build.internal.FetchStyleLoadPlanBuildingAssociationVisitationStrategy - Building LoadPlan...
19:26:33.050 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.LoadQueryJoinAndFetchProcessor - processing queryspace <gen:0>
19:26:33.054 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.loader.plan.build.spi.LoadPlanTreePrinter - LoadPlan(entity=br.com.api.entities.Persona)
    - Returns
       - EntityReturnImpl(entity=br.com.api.entities.Persona, querySpaceUid=<gen:0>, path=br.com.api.entities.Persona)
    - QuerySpaces
       - EntityQuerySpaceImpl(uid=<gen:0>, entity=br.com.api.entities.Persona)
          - SQL table alias mapping - persona0_
          - alias suffix - 0_
          - suffixed key columns - {id1_0_0_}

19:26:33.056 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.loader.entity.plan.EntityLoader - Static select for entity br.com.api.entities.Persona [NONE]: select persona0_.id as id1_0_0_, persona0_.description as descript2_0_0_, persona0_.modified as modified3_0_0_, persona0_.name as name4_0_0_, persona0_.resourceURI as resource5_0_0_ from Persona persona0_ where persona0_.id=?
19:26:33.102 [main] INFO org.hibernate.orm.connections.access - HHH10001501: Connection obtained from JdbcConnectionAccess [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess@52b959df] for (non-JTA) DDL execution was not in auto-commit mode; the Connection 'local transaction' will be committed and the Connection will be set into auto-commit mode.
19:26:33.124 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.mapping.Table - No alter strings for table : Persona
19:26:33.125 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.JtaPlatformInitiator - No JtaPlatform was specified, checking resolver
19:26:33.126 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.JtaPlatformResolverInitiator - No JtaPlatformResolver was specified, using default [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.StandardJtaPlatformResolver]
19:26:33.134 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.StandardJtaPlatformResolver - Could not resolve JtaPlatform, using default [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
19:26:33.134 [main] INFO org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.JtaPlatformInitiator - HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
19:26:33.135 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.query.spi.NamedQueryRepository - Checking 0 named HQL queries
19:26:33.135 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.query.spi.NamedQueryRepository - Checking 0 named SQL queries
19:26:33.151 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryRegistry - Initializing SessionFactoryRegistry : org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryRegistry@2dd1086
19:26:33.153 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryRegistry - Registering SessionFactory: ec49aefc-f7c7-4367-97a4-ab4156937eee (<unnamed>)
19:26:33.153 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryRegistry - Not binding SessionFactory to JNDI, no JNDI name configured
19:26:33.215 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.stat.internal.StatisticsInitiator - Statistics initialized [enabled=false]
19:26:33.237 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.query.criteria.internal.CriteriaQueryImpl - Rendered criteria query -> select generatedAlias0 from Persona as generatedAlias0
19:26:33.250 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.hql.internal.QueryTranslatorFactoryInitiator - QueryTranslatorFactory: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory@2c6c302f
19:26:33.273 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl - parse() - HQL: select generatedAlias0 from br.com.api.entities.Persona as generatedAlias0
19:26:33.277 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ErrorTracker - throwQueryException() : no errors
19:26:33.284 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl - --- HQL AST ---
 \-[QUERY] Node: 'query'
    \-[SELECT_FROM] Node: 'SELECT_FROM'
       +-[FROM] Node: 'from'
       |  \-[RANGE] Node: 'RANGE'
       |     +-[DOT] Node: '.'
       |     |  +-[DOT] Node: '.'
       |     |  |  +-[DOT] Node: '.'
       |     |  |  |  +-[DOT] Node: '.'
       |     |  |  |  |  +-[IDENT] Node: 'br'
       |     |  |  |  |  \-[IDENT] Node: 'com'
       |     |  |  |  \-[IDENT] Node: 'api'
       |     |  |  \-[IDENT] Node: 'entities'
       |     |  \-[IDENT] Node: 'Persona'
       |     \-[ALIAS] Node: 'generatedAlias0'
       \-[SELECT] Node: 'select'
          \-[IDENT] Node: 'generatedAlias0'

19:26:33.301 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker - select << begin [level=1, statement=select]
19:26:33.313 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.FromElement - FromClause{level=1} : br.com.api.entities.Persona (generatedAlias0) -> persona0_
19:26:33.314 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.FromReferenceNode - Resolved : generatedAlias0 -> persona0_.id
19:26:33.316 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker - select : finishing up [level=1, statement=select]
19:26:33.316 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.HqlSqlWalker - processQuery() :  ( SELECT ( {select clause} persona0_.id ) ( FromClause{level=1} Persona persona0_ ) )
19:26:33.322 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.util.JoinProcessor - Tables referenced from query nodes:
 \-QueryNode
    +-SelectClause
    | referencedTables(entity Persona): [Persona]
    |  +-IdentNode
    |  | persister: SingleTableEntityPersister(br.com.api.entities.Persona)
    |  | originalText: generatedAlias0
    |  \-SqlFragment
    \-FromClause
       \-FromElement

19:26:33.325 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.util.JoinProcessor - Using FROM fragment [Persona persona0_]
19:26:33.325 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker - select >> end [level=1, statement=select]
19:26:33.326 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl - --- SQL AST ---
 \-[SELECT] QueryNode: 'SELECT'  querySpaces (Persona)
    +-[SELECT_CLAUSE] SelectClause: '{select clause}'
    |  +-[ALIAS_REF] IdentNode: 'persona0_.id as id1_0_' {alias=generatedAlias0, className=br.com.api.entities.Persona, tableAlias=persona0_}
    |  \-[SQL_TOKEN] SqlFragment: 'persona0_.description as descript2_0_, persona0_.modified as modified3_0_, persona0_.name as name4_0_, persona0_.resourceURI as resource5_0_'
    \-[FROM] FromClause: 'from' FromClause{level=1, fromElementCounter=1, fromElements=1, fromElementByClassAlias=[generatedAlias0], fromElementByTableAlias=[persona0_], fromElementsByPath=[], collectionJoinFromElementsByPath=[], impliedElements=[]}
       \-[FROM_FRAGMENT] FromElement: 'Persona persona0_' FromElement{explicit,not a collection join,not a fetch join,fetch non-lazy properties,classAlias=generatedAlias0,role=null,tableName=Persona,tableAlias=persona0_,origin=null,columns={,className=br.com.api.entities.Persona}}

19:26:33.326 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ErrorTracker - throwQueryException() : no errors
19:26:33.331 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl - HQL: select generatedAlias0 from br.com.api.entities.Persona as generatedAlias0
19:26:33.331 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl - SQL: select persona0_.id as id1_0_, persona0_.description as descript2_0_, persona0_.modified as modified3_0_, persona0_.name as name4_0_, persona0_.resourceURI as resource5_0_ from Persona persona0_
19:26:33.331 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ErrorTracker - throwQueryException() : no errors
19:26:33.344 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.SQL - select persona0_.id as id1_0_, persona0_.description as descript2_0_, persona0_.modified as modified3_0_, persona0_.name as name4_0_, persona0_.resourceURI as resource5_0_ from Persona persona0_
19:26:33.348 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.loader.Loader - Result set row: 0
19:26:33.351 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.loader.Loader - Result row: EntityKey[br.com.api.entities.Persona#1]
19:26:33.357 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.loader.Loader - Result set row: 1
19:26:33.357 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.loader.Loader - Result row: EntityKey[br.com.api.entities.Persona#2]
19:26:33.357 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.loader.Loader - Result set row: 2
19:26:33.357 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.loader.Loader - Result row: EntityKey[br.com.api.entities.Persona#3]
19:26:33.357 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.loader.Loader - Result set row: 3
19:26:33.357 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.loader.Loader - Result row: EntityKey[br.com.api.entities.Persona#4]
19:26:33.359 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad - Resolving attributes for [br.com.api.entities.Persona#1]
19:26:33.360 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad - Processing attribute `description` : value = Teste
19:26:33.360 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad - Attribute (`description`)  - enhanced for lazy-loading? - false
19:26:33.360 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad - Processing attribute `modified` : value = null
19:26:33.361 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad - Attribute (`modified`)  - enhanced for lazy-loading? - false
19:26:33.361 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad - Processing attribute `name` : value = T
19:26:33.361 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad - Attribute (`name`)  - enhanced for lazy-loading? - false
19:26:33.361 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad - Processing attribute `resourceURI` : value = null
19:26:33.361 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad - Attribute (`resourceURI`)  - enhanced for lazy-loading? - false
19:26:33.362 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad - Done materializing entity [br.com.api.entities.Persona#1]
19:26:33.362 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad - Resolving attributes for [br.com.api.entities.Persona#2]
19:26:33.362 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad - Processing attribute `description` : value = Teste
19:26:33.362 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad - Attribute (`description`)  - enhanced for lazy-loading? - false
19:26:33.362 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad - Processing attribute `modified` : value = null
19:26:33.363 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad - Attribute (`modified`)  - enhanced for lazy-loading? - false
19:26:33.363 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad - Processing attribute `name` : value = T
19:26:33.363 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad - Attribute (`name`)  - enhanced for lazy-loading? - false
19:26:33.363 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad - Processing attribute `resourceURI` : value = null
19:26:33.363 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad - Attribute (`resourceURI`)  - enhanced for lazy-loading? - false
19:26:33.363 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad - Done materializing entity [br.com.api.entities.Persona#2]
19:26:33.363 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad - Resolving attributes for [br.com.api.entities.Persona#3]
19:26:33.364 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad - Processing attribute `description` : value = Teste
19:26:33.364 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad - Attribute (`description`)  - enhanced for lazy-loading? - false
19:26:33.364 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad - Processing attribute `modified` : value = null
19:26:33.364 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad - Attribute (`modified`)  - enhanced for lazy-loading? - false
19:26:33.364 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad - Processing attribute `name` : value = T
19:26:33.364 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad - Attribute (`name`)  - enhanced for lazy-loading? - false
19:26:33.364 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad - Processing attribute `resourceURI` : value = null
19:26:33.364 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad - Attribute (`resourceURI`)  - enhanced for lazy-loading? - false
19:26:33.364 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad - Done materializing entity [br.com.api.entities.Persona#3]
19:26:33.364 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad - Resolving attributes for [br.com.api.entities.Persona#4]
19:26:33.364 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad - Processing attribute `description` : value = Teste
19:26:33.364 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad - Attribute (`description`)  - enhanced for lazy-loading? - false
19:26:33.364 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad - Processing attribute `modified` : value = null
19:26:33.364 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad - Attribute (`modified`)  - enhanced for lazy-loading? - false
19:26:33.365 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad - Processing attribute `name` : value = T
19:26:33.365 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad - Attribute (`name`)  - enhanced for lazy-loading? - false
19:26:33.365 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad - Processing attribute `resourceURI` : value = null
19:26:33.365 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad - Attribute (`resourceURI`)  - enhanced for lazy-loading? - false
19:26:33.365 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad - Done materializing entity [br.com.api.entities.Persona#4]
19:26:33.368 [main] DEBUG org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl - Initiating JDBC connection release from afterTransaction
Persona [id=1, name=T, description=Teste, modified=null, resourceURI=null]
Persona [id=2, name=T, description=Teste, modified=null, resourceURI=null]
Persona [id=3, name=T, description=Teste, modified=null, resourceURI=null]
Persona [id=4, name=T, description=Teste, modified=null, resourceURI=null]
```

Answer (score 0):

Provavelmente está faltando um JAR na sua aplicação. Tente adicionar a biblioteca `hibernate-jpa-2.1-api`. Dependendo da versão do *Hibernate* este JAR já está incluso, apenas certifique.

Comment: Foi adicionada a dependência
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.2.Final</version>
</dependency>

mas o erro persiste.

Answer (score 0):

Verifique se as versões do Hibernate e do Spring são compatíveis. Se puder colocar as dependências que está utilizando no projeto